# Tetrations of non-integers?

Tags: tetration

A Tetration is defined as $${^{n}a} = \underbrace{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{a}}}}}_n$$ or, by a recursion function, $${^{n}a} := \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }n=0 \\ a^{\left[^{(n-1)}a\right]} &\text{if }n>0 \end{cases} $$ That is, iterated exponentiation (like exponentiation is iterated multiplication). Exponentiation can be expressed as $e^{n\ln a}$ [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/how-to-calculate-a-decimal-power-of-a-number)

Is there a like way to express Tetrations? That is, a way to calculate for both *negative* and decimal Tetrations?

Comment: The comments at [Arrow notation and decimals.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546032/arrow-notation-and-decimals) may be helpful.

Comment: Also relevant: [Is there a natural way to extend repeated exponentiation beyond integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56663/is-there-a-natural-way-to-extend-repeated-exponentiation-beyond-integers/56710#56710)